# OutputCache NoStore not working on MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I need to disable the Browser Navigation from an specific action in MVC 5.

For this purpose I have tried this:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration=0)]

[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration=0, VaryByParam="*")]

[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration=0, VaryByParam="None")]
```

But is not working.

I really need to disable the navigation. IT IS A REQUIREMENT! And I do not want to achieve this using Javascrip

Comment: `OutputCache` if for controlling how the page is cached on the server and client. What do you mean disable _browser navigation_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable the navigation, as in make it go away or make it unclickable, you will need to modify the CSHTML that renders the HTML page containing the link, so that the link does not get rendered in the first place or cannot be clicked.

You are trying to modify the controller, which is the code that is called in response to an HTTP request.  The OutputCache attribute controls whether and for how long the HTML generated by the decorated action is cached by MVC, not whether any link in an already rendered HTML page is visible to or navigable by the user.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation